# A member-function of a managed type cannot be compiled as an unmanaged function

Tags: c++, c++-cli

This is the 2nd form in my program, and it generates the above error. The constructor function is what generates the error, and I can't see why. It's pretty much the same as my main window's constructor, which works just fine.

The only difference is that this one takes an argument. (even if I remove the argument in the SettingsForm constructor, and revert back to `void`, I still get the same error.

Can anybody tell me why it seems to think this constructor is being compiled as an unmanaged 
function?

SettingsForm.h

```
#pragma once
#pragma managed(push, off)
#include "SpriteyData.h"
#pragma managed(pop)

namespace Spritey {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;
    using namespace SpriteyData;

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for SettingsForm
    /// </summary>
    public ref class SettingsForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {

    public:
        SpriteySettings* currentSetLocCopy;//A local copy of our current settings.

        SettingsForm(SpriteySettings* currentSettings)<------ERROR OCCURS HERE
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            currentSetLocCopy = new SpriteySettings(*currentSettings); //take a copy of our current settings
            //initialise the elements on our form to the values stored in the SpriteySettings
            this->anchorDevCheckBox->Checked = currentSetLocCopy->isAnchorDevAllowed();
        }



    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        ~SettingsForm()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;

            }
            if(currentSetLocCopy)
            {
                delete currentSetLocCopy;
            }
        }
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  CancelButton;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  ApplyButton;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::GroupBox^  editorSettingsGroup;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::CheckBox^  anchorDevCheckBox;
    private:
```

**Note:** The above is just the constructor + a bit more of the code, and is merely a code sample of the part that is causing the error.

Also this is a mixed managed & unmanaged project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Repro for this compile error:

```
#pragma managed(push, off)
class SpriteySettings {};

ref class Test
{
public:
    Test(SpriteySettings* arg) {}
};
```

> error C3280: 'Test::Test' : a member-function of a managed type cannot be compiled as an unmanaged function

As well as a slew of additional errors.  So the diagnostic is that this code is getting compiled *without* the /clr compile option in effect.  Since this is a .h file, the likely cause is you #including it in a .cpp file that is being compiled without /clr.  You'll need to find that #include directive.

Comment: The file was being `#include`d in another form's .h file. Although that .h file was set to compile with \clr, it was `#include`d in between `#pragma managed(push,off)`, and`pragma managed(pop)`. 
I moved it outside of these directives and the problem was solved.
Thanks again Hans.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue. On adding .Net Target Framework Version as v4.5.1 (which was missing previously) , the issue was resolved